# Rule development and deployment management with Drools Guvnor

Tags: drools, rule-engine, business-rules, drools-guvnor, guvnor

### Introduction

Drools Guvnor has it's own versioning system, that in production use allows the users of an application to modify the rules and decision tables in order to adapt to change in their business. Yet, the same assets continue to live on the development version control system, where new features to the app are developed.

This post is for looking insight/ideas/experience on rule development and deployment when working with Drools rules and Guvnor.

Below are some key concepts I've been puzzling about.

### Deployment to Guvnor

First of all, what is the best way to deploy the drl files and decision tables to production environment? Just simply put them on a zip package and then unzip to Web-Dav folder? What I have navigated around Drools, I haven't found a way to import more than one file at a time. The fact model can be added as a jar archive, though. Guvnor seems to have a REST API of some sort, but using that would require custom deployment scripts.

### Change management

Secondly, once the application is in production, the users will likely want to change the values in decision tables in order to set the discount percentages to higher for premium clients etc. This is all fine and dandy, until comes the time to start development of version 2.0 of the app.

Now what we have at this point is

- drl files and decision tables in **version controlling system**
- drl files and decision tables in production environment with user modifications, **versioned by Guvnor**

Now we are in the point of getting the rules and decision tables back from the Guvnor. And again is the Web-Dav folder the best for this, what other options there are?

Merge tools today can even handle Excel file diffs, but sounds like a merge hell to me on a big scale projects.

### Keeping the fact model backwards compatible

Yet another topic is fact model integrity. For the assumed version 2.0, developers always want to make refactoring and tear the whole fact model upside down. Still, it must remain backwards compatible with the previous versions as there may be user modified rules that depend on that. Any tips on this? Just keep the fact model simple and clean? Plan ahead / suggest what the users could want to change?

### Summary

I'm certain I'm not the first, and surely not the last, to consider options on deployment and change management with Drools and Guvnor. So, what I'd like to hear is comment, discussion, tips etc. on some best (and also the worst in order to avoid them) practices to handle these situations.

Thanks.

Comment: The assigned bounty is already marked for @Steve, but who knows, maybe there'll be more available if another such a great answer comes along :)

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do things depends very much on your specific application and the environment you work in. However the following are pointers from my own experience. Note that I'll add just a few points for now. I'll probably come back to this answer when things come to me.

**After the initial go-live, keep releases incremental and small**

For your first release you have the opportunity to try things out. Take advantage of this opportunity, and do as much refactoring as possible, because...

Your application has gone live and your business users are maintaining rules in decision tables. You have made great gains in what folks in the industry like to call "business agility". Unfortunately, this tends to be at the expense of application development agility. All of your guided editor rules and decision table rules are tied to your fact model, so any changes existing properties of that fact model will break your decision tables. Unlike in most IDEs these days, you can't just right-click on a fact's getX() method, rename it, and expect all code which relies on that property to be updated.

Decision tables and guided rules are hard to refactor. If a fact has been renamed, then in many (all?) versions of Guvnor, that rule/table will no longer open. You need to get at the underlying XML file via WebDav and do some text searching and replacing. That may be very difficult, considering that to do this, you need to download the file from production to a test environment, make changes, test them, deploy them to a test environment. When you're happy with your changes you need to push them back up to the 'production' Guvnor. Unfortunately, while you were doing that, the users have updated a number of decision tables and you need to either start again, or re-apply the past couple of days' changes. In an ideal world, your business users will agree to make no rule changes for a period of time. But the only way to make that feasible is to keep the changes small so that you can make them in a couple of hours or a day depending on how generous they feel.

To mitigate this:

1. Keep facts used within Guvnor separate from your application domain classes. Your application developers can then refactor the internal application model to their hearts content, but such changes will not affect the business model. Maintain mappings between the two and ensure there are tests covering those mappings.
2. Avoid changes such as renaming facts or their properties. Make sure that facts you create and their properties have names which suit the domain and agree these with the business. On the other hand, adding a new property is relatively painless. It is well worth prompting the users to give you an eye on their future plans.
3. Keep facts as simple as possible. Don't go more complex than name-value pairs unless you really need to. For one thing, your business users will find it much easier to maintain rules. Your priority with anything managed within Guvnor should always be about making it easy for business users to maintain.
4. Keep external dependencies out of your facts. A developer may think it's a good idea to annotate a fact as a JPA @Entity, for easy persistence. Unfortunately, that adds dependencies which need to be added to Guvnor's classpath, requiring a restart.

**Tips & tricks**

My personal technique for making cross-environment changes is to connect Eclipse to two Guvnor WebDav directories, and checkout the rules into local directories, where each local directory maps to an environment. I then use the Eclipse diff tooling.

When building a Guvnor-managed knowledge base, I create a separate Maven project containing only the facts, and with no dependencies on anything else. It makes it a lot easier to keep them clean this way. Also, when I really do need to add a dependency (i.e. I use JodaTime where possible), then the build can have a step to generate a shaded JAR containing all the dependencies. That way you only ever deploy one JAR to Guvnor, which is guaranteed to contain the correct versions of your dependencies.

I'm sure there will be more that I think of. I'll try to remember to come back to this...

Comment: Thanks @Steve for the excellent pointers. That pretty much covers all parts of change management and fact domain integrity. Got any more pointers on the initial deployment/import of the rules and decision tables? Is WebDav the way to go?

Comment: P.S. I decided to award you a bounty of 100 rep for this and other excellent answers you've given at SO to help Drools community. Unfortunately, you'll have to wait for it 23 hours.

Comment: :D Thanks for that! I recently decided that to get more people into Drools, the documentation available online was in need of improvement, so I started working through the Drools user guides, fixing them up and firing pull requests at the team. I also noticed that most answers on SO seemed a bit cursory, so I have given myself a mission to try and create some decent quality answers. Hopefully it will be a helpful contribution to ease entry into Drools for the beginners out there and to take some of the burden off the core team.