# Custom UI to add/edit/delete drools file

Tags: drools, rule-engine, drools-guvnor

I want to load drool file in to my custom UI, and modify or delete few rules and  upload back. is there any opensource or some features available in drool itself to do this?

I went through few dozen links like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715751/fetch-and-edit-drools-rules-in-java) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51178210/how-to-update-rules-dynamically-in-drools-rule-engine) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964082/rule-development-and-deployment-management-with-drools-guvnor) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60936309/difference-between-drools-engine-and-database)

Is the only way to store rules in  my domain model in a database and generating the DRL from that model to have custom UI?

Comment: Asking for third party tools and recommendations is off topic.

Comment: The official option is the drools workbench. If that doesn't suit your needs, a homebrew based on your specific use cases is the solution.